# How can I make this algorithm work with minimal time increase - 4sum

Tags: python, algorithm

Created this algorithm for 4sum last night and on all coding websites it very generally works, however, there are a few cases where the output list is missing one possible quadruplet, which, seems to be a problem associated with the input list's order, yet, I'm not completely sure. To me, it seems the code should work fine for the problem, but, if the problems not the order it must be a small detail I'm missing.

```
def fourSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        dic = {}
        ans = set()
        nums.sort()
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
                rem = nums[i] + nums[j]
                if target - (rem) in dic:
                    for z in dic[target - (rem)]:
                        if i not in z and j not in z:
                            maybe2 = sorted([nums[i], nums[j], nums[z[1]], nums[z[0]]])
                            ans.add(tuple(maybe2))
                else:
                    if rem in dic:
                        dic[rem].append([i, j])
                    else:
                        dic[rem] = [[i,j]]
        return [list(a) for a in ans]
```

This algorithm itself was derived from a brute-force solution which worked in all cases but was too inefficient, and so that's what led me to the idea that the problem is the list's order, and, more specifically, that I'm not iterating through the list enough times. In any case, again, the code generally works but one quadruplet will be missing from the output list every once in a blue moon, so to speak.

For example, on LeetCode, the input list nums is:
[0,2,2,2,10,-3,-9,2,-10,-4,-9,-2,2,8,7]
and the desired output (target 6) is:
[[-10,-2,8,10],[-9,-3,8,10],[-9,-2,7,10],[-9,0,7,8],[-4,-2,2,10],[-4,0,2,8],[-3,0,2,7],[0,2,2,2]]

However, my code will return
[[-9,0,7,8],[-10,-2,8,10],[-3,0,2,7],[-4,0,2,8],[-4,-2,2,10],[-9,-3,8,10],[-9,-2,7,10]]

And so one quadruplet, [0,2,2,2], fails to appear in my output list.

Comment: hi juicy! welcome to stackoverflow. can you be more specific about where it fails? give an example input please, and the desired solution

Comment: Hi, Mark. I added an example in my original post.

Comment: Your dictionary needs to be a list of possible pairs, not just a single pair.

Comment: The `else:` line is wrong.  You should never skip putting a pair of indices in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You require that neither `i` or `j` should be in a pair found as a complement in `dic`(awful name - don't name for what something is, but for what use it is).
This precludes tuples with a single value occurring 3 or 4 times.